# SQL-92 (Filemaker): How can I UPDATE a list of sequential numbers?

Tags: sql, filemaker

I need to re-assign all SortID's, starting from 1 until MAX (SortID) from a subset of records of table Beleg, using SQL-92, after one of the SortID's has changed (for example from 444 to 444.1).  I have tried several ways (for example SET @a:=0; UPDATE table SET field=@a:=@a+1 WHERE whatever='whatever' ORDER BY field2), but it didn't work, as these solutions all need a special kind of SQL, like SQLServer or Oracle, etc.

The SQL that I use is SQL-92, implemented in FileMaker (INSERT and UPDATE are available, though, but nothing fancy).

Thanks for any hint!

Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer from [Ziggy Crueltyfree Zeitgeister](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/55596/ziggy-crueltyfree-zeitgeister) on [the Database Administrators copy of my question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/135237).

He suggested to break this down into multiple steps using a temporary table to store the results:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE sorting (sid numeric(10,10), rn int);
>
> INSERT INTO sorting (sid, rn)
> SELECT SortID, RecordNumber FROM Beleg
> WHERE Year ( Valuta ) = 2016
> AND Ursprungskonto = 1210
> ORDER BY SortID;
>
> UPDATE Beleg SET SortID = (SELECT rn FROM sorting WHERE sid=Beleg.SortID)
> WHERE Year ( Valuta ) = 2016
> AND Ursprungskonto = 1210;
>
> DROP TABLE sorting;
> ```

Of course! I just keep the table definition in Filemaker (let the type coercion be done by Filemaker this way), and filling and deleting from it with my function: RenumberSortID ().

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, SQL-92 is a standard and not a language. So you can say you are using T-SQL, which is mostly SQL-92 compliant, but you can't say I program SQL Server in SQL-92. The same applies to FileMaker.

I suppose you are trying to update your table through ODBC? The Update statement looks OK, but there are no variables if FileMaker SQL (and I am not sure using a variable inside query will give you result you expect, I think you will set SortId in every row to 1). You are thinking about doing something like Window functions with row() in TSQL, but I do not think this functionality is available.

The easiest solution is to use FileMaker, resetting the numbering for a column is really a trivial task which takes seconds. Do you need help with this?

Edit:

I was referring to TSQL functions rank() and row_number(), there is no row() function in TSQL

Comment: Thanks; it is very easy with Filemaker -- if you are in the correct found set, but very clumsy otherwise. That's why I'm looking for an SQL solution.

Comment: Which SQL Database do you use:  FileMaker itself (via executeSQL) or a different one?

Comment: I'm using the epSQLExecute function from Dracoventions (which is basically Filemaker's executeSQL function, but with INSERT and UPDATE added to it).

Comment: The closest answer I could find is here:https://community.filemaker.com/thread/74404?start=0&tstart=0