# Can't update sort numbers using SQL-92 (Filemaker)

Tags: sql, sorting, filemaker

Please help, I want to update my SortID's with new ascending numbers, but can't figure it out, how, because FileMaker's SQL is quite limited.

I can't use FileMaker to do this because I don't want to loose the current FoundSet.

There is a FileMaker function RecordNumber, which I'm using here. It always returns ascending numbers, no matter how the result is sorted.

Here is my table, using RecordNumber:

```
SELECT SortID, RecordNumber FROM Beleg
WHERE Year ( Valuta ) = 2016
AND Ursprungskonto = 1210
ORDER BY SortID
```

Produces:

```
.5  1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10  10
10.000001   11
10.000002   12
```

Looks fine. But I can't leave the ORDER BY in, when I use UPDATE, I get an error.

However, when I take ORDER BY out, my SortID's will be updated wrongly. This is what the list looks like when I leave the ORDER BY out:

```
SELECT SortID, RecordNumber FROM Beleg
WHERE Year ( Valuta ) = 2016
AND Ursprungskonto = 1210
```

Produces this:

```
2   1
3   2
.5  3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10  10
10.000001   11
10.000002   12
```

Using the statement:

```
UPDATE Beleg SET SortID = RecordNumber
WHERE Year ( Valuta ) = 2016
AND Ursprungskonto = 1210
```

I get the wrong values in SortID. 0.5 should be updated with 1 and not with 3.

I'm lost. Any ideas how to write ascending numbers into my SortID column?

Thanks a lot!

Gary

Comment: Doesn't make any sense

Comment: There is no internal order in most SQL RDBMS.  So you can update without worrying about this.

Comment: When I update, it gets updated with the wrong numbers. Because the result is in the order in which the records are created, not according to the values stored in SortID.

Comment: "*I can't use FileMaker to do this because I don't want to loose the current FoundSet.*" That's not a valid reason. Open a new window, do whatever is necessary - and when you close that window, you will be returned to your original window, with its found set untouched.

Comment: I understand, this is how one is supposed to do this in FileMaker. But it's ugly and a potential trouble maker. I used temp windows in the past and got only problems in the long run.  I just want to make one short SQL call.

Comment: "*potential trouble maker.*" No, it's not. And it's not the only way to preserve a found set. SQL should be your last resort, not first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ziggy Crueltyfree Zeitgeister on [Stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34451932/sql-92-filemaker-how-can-i-update-a-list-of-sequential-numbers?rq=1) I got the answer!

He suggested to break this down into multiple steps using a temporary table to store the results:

```
CREATE TABLE sorting (sid numeric(10,10), rn int);

INSERT INTO sorting (sid, rn)
SELECT SortID, RecordNumber FROM Beleg
WHERE Year ( Valuta ) = 2016
AND Ursprungskonto = 1210
ORDER BY SortID;

UPDATE Beleg SET SortID = (SELECT rn FROM sorting WHERE sid=Beleg.SortID)
WHERE Year ( Valuta ) = 2016
AND Ursprungskonto = 1210;

DROP TABLE sorting;
```

Of course! I just made the table definition in Filemaker and keep it around (let the type coercion be done by Filemaker this way), and filling and deleting from it with my function: RenumberSortID ().